# The usage of 有 in comparisons

Tags: grammar, comparison

The verb 有 can be used to form a sentence in a way of comparisons of equality as follows. (as ~ as)

> 今天有昨天热。Today is as hot as yesterday.
>
> 他没有你细心。He is not as careful as you.

From looking at them, it seems to me that Mandarin uses a phrase (noun+adjective) as one word, for example in the above two sentences:

> 昨天-热 (hot as yesterday)
> 你-细心(careful as you)

Am I getting it correct? If yes, can I do the make-up-new-word thing when I speak English in Mandarin too as long as it fits well?

or this is not a good catch at all?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It's more natural to say 今天有昨天那么热

Comment: Think in this way: 今天有昨天热 Today has yesterday's hot = Today has the same amount of hot as yesterday = Today is as hot as yesterday. You can understand  有 as a verb here. It's not used as "as", which is an adverb in "Today is as hot as yesterday.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When use `有` in comparison:

In positive way you can use 今天和昨天一样热(Today is as hot as yesterday) or 今天有昨天那么热 instead of 今天有昨天热.Because it's more normal expression.

In negative way you can use `他没(有)你(那么)细心` which will omit character `有` or `今天没(有)昨天(那么)热`.

It's better to add 那么 in comparison to emphasize comparison.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to see the whole picture of comparison than just one case, right?

Let us see how to say: A = B, A > B, and A < B.

今天和昨天一样热。Today is as hot as yesterday. 这个和那个一样+adj。

今天比昨天(还要)热。Today is hotter than yesterday. 这个比那个(还要)+adj。

今天没有昨天热。Today is less hot than yesterday. 这个没有那个+adj。

Except the above, there are many alternatives. Sometimes, you can simply insert 不，没，but many times you can not do so because Chinese do not work as a "LOGIC" robot. For example, Chinese people do not say 今天有昨天热。But then do say: 今天有昨天热吗？I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

今天和昨天一样热 is better according to my friends.

but the negative '他没有你细心。' is ok.

Comment: That sentence was supposed to be a negative form, but I removed 没 to just show that both positive and negative forms even out. If those given examples sound not good enough, please let me know so that I can write more and longer examples. Thanks!